# Rails Sending the id in the wrong spot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller called prattachments which has a restful route inside of purchase_requests, but when I try to send a delete request by using this in an each_with_index block:

```
link_to "delete", purchase_request_prattachment_path(attachment), :method=>:delete
```

This route, according to `rake routes` should be:

```
purchase_request_prattachment DELETE /purchase_requests/:purchase_request_id/prattachments/:id {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"prattachments"}
```

however, when it is called it reverses :purchase_request and :id, anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: call to path should be something like `purchase_request_prattachment_path([purchase_request, attachment])`

Comment: can you provide the route file details.

Comment: @RubishGupta that looks right. Why not enter that as an answer so this question can be marked answered?

Comment: @Rubish Gupta, that worked.  Put it in an answer and I will accept it as the best answer.

Comment: @jdeseno: had not tested it, was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call to path should be:

```
purchase_request_prattachment_path(purchase_request, attachment)
```